# Toggle Anchor Tag Background on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a div I have an anchor tag. That anchor tag has a background image assigned to it using CSS.

When the user clicks on it, some JavaScript is executed, but I want to change the background image to another, then when they click on it again, the background image changes back to what it was originally.

Any help on how to do this (JQuery, CSS; I'm unsure) would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toggleClass to change the background image.

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('class2');
});
​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/NNcG5/9/)**

Comment: Could use `this` instead of the inner reference to `#div1` again, just to reduce duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Save the property of the anchor -- before the state change -- into a variable. Then add that variable into the `data` of the object. From here, we can add a class to the link to test which scenario we need to serve. For the purpose of this example, I used colors and the `background-color` property, you can change this to fit your needs very easily.

**[Here's the working jsFiddle of my example](http://jsfiddle.net/yfJka/)**

Here's the HTML Structure ->

```
<div>
  <a href="#" style="background-color:blue;">
    Click To Change
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery ->

```
$('a').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('oldbg'));
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass('clicked');  

    var oldBG = $(this).css('background-color');
    //the above stores the original css properties to a variable 'oldBG'

    $(this).data('oldbg', oldBG);
    //set the data of this object to the properties of the initial background.
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');  
  }
});
```